# Pandas dataframe multiplication

Tags: python, pandas

Let say I have two dataframes with matching multiindex:

something like this

*numbers_by_stages* =

```
                            Stage I No  Stage II No  Stage III No  Stage IV No  Stage NA No
Gender Cancer                                                                              
Male   Colon & rectum      1238.058000  1428.057000   1881.603000  1575.153000          NaN
       Prostate             708.576000  1406.416000   1583.560000  1669.448000          NaN
       Lung                 691.288000   299.897000    904.774000  3187.041000          NaN
       Liver                981.848000   377.846000    750.176000   648.130000          NaN
       Lymphoid neoplasms          NaN          NaN           NaN          NaN  2358.000000
       Non-melanoma skin           NaN          NaN           NaN          NaN  1975.000000
```

and *percentage_by_age_groups* =

```
                           0-29 years  30-39 years  40-49 years  50-59 years  60-69 years  70-79 years  80+ years
Gender Cancer                                                                                                    
Male   Colon & rectum        0.005058     0.015011     0.056942     0.192690     0.341002     0.250775   0.138522
       Prostate                   NaN          NaN          NaN     0.091370     0.384991     0.379737   0.143902
       Lung                       NaN     0.006302     0.034462     0.140410     0.303466     0.323159   0.192202
       Liver                      NaN          NaN     0.046401     0.185970     0.340153     0.278772   0.148703
       Lymphoid neoplasms    0.112807     0.045802     0.090331     0.170908     0.259118     0.216709   0.104326
       Non-melanoma skin          NaN     0.022877     0.080834     0.146416     0.238434     0.257753   0.253686
```

I would like to multiply one by another to get numbers by stage in each age group. It could be a dataframe with same number of rows but with 5x7 columns ('Stage I No in 0-29 years', 'Stage II No in 30-39 years', ..., 'Stage NA No in 80+ years')

or dataframe with only one column but with many rows with third and fourth level index:

```
                              
Gender Cancer                                                                              
Male   Colon & rectum   Stage I No      0-29 years      1238.058000*0.005058
                                        30-39 years     1238.058000*0.015011
                                        ... 
                                        80+ years       1238.058000*0.138522
                        Stage II No     0-29 years      1428.057000*0.005058
                                        30-39 years     1428.057000*0.015011
                                        ... 
                                        70-79 years     1428.057000*0.250775
                                        80+ years       1428.057000*0.138522
```

There must be some python magic to do it in a few lines! Please advise

**Update**: code to play with

```
numbers_by_stages = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1238.058000, 1428.057000, 1881.603000, 1575.153000, np.NaN],
                            [708.576000, 1406.416000, 1583.560000, 1669.448000, np.NaN],
                            [691.288000, 299.897000, 904.774000, 3187.041000, np.NaN],
                            [981.848000, 377.846000, 750.176000, 648.130000, np.NaN],
                            [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 2358.000000],
                            [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 1975.000000]]),
                  columns=['Stage I No', 'Stage II No', 'Stage III No', 'Stage IV No', 'Stage NA No'],
                  index=[['Male', 'Male',  'Male',  'Male',  'Male',  'Male'], 
                         ['Colon & rectum', 'Prostate', 'Lung', 'Liver', 'Lymphoid neoplasms', 'Non-melanoma skin']])

percentage_by_age_groups = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0.005058, 0.015011, 0.056942, 0.192690, 0.341002, 0.250775, 0.138522],
                            [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 0.091370, 0.384991, 0.379737, 0.143902],
                            [np.NaN, 0.006302, 0.034462, 0.140410, 0.303466, 0.323159, 0.192202],
                            [np.NaN, np.NaN, 0.046401, 0.185970, 0.340153, 0.278772, 0.148703],
                            [0.112807, 0.045802, 0.090331, 0.170908, 0.259118, 0.216709, 0.104326],
                            [np.NaN, 0.022877, 0.080834, 0.146416, 0.238434, 0.257753, 0.253686]]),
                  columns=['0-29 years', '30-39 years', '40-49 years', '50-59 years', '60-69 years', '70-79 years', '80+ years'],
                  index=[['Male', 'Male',  'Male',  'Male',  'Male',  'Male'], 
                         ['Colon & rectum', 'Prostate', 'Lung', 'Liver', 'Lymphoid neoplasms', 'Non-melanoma skin']])
```

Comment: MultiIndex dataframes are hard to read using `read_clipboard`, please provide both the dataframes in `dict` format.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I've added code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stack` the dataframe `numbers_by_stages` to reshape into a MultiIndex series, then `rename` the index levels to `Gender`, `Cancer` and `Stage`. Now multiply this series with the dataframe `percentage_by_age_groups` along the index axis then `stack` to reshape in the desired format

```
p = percentage_by_age_groups.rename_axis(['Gender', 'Cancer'])
s = numbers_by_stages.stack(dropna=False).rename_axis(['Gender', 'Cancer', 'Stage'])

p.mul(s, axis=0).stack(dropna=False)
```

---

```
Gender  Cancer          Stage                   
Male    Colon & rectum  Stage I No   0-29 years       6.262097
                                     30-39 years     18.584489
                                     40-49 years     70.497499
                                     50-59 years    238.561396
                                     60-69 years    422.180254
                                                       ...    
        Prostate        Stage NA No  40-49 years           NaN
                                     50-59 years           NaN
                                     60-69 years           NaN
                                     70-79 years           NaN
                                     80+ years             NaN
Length: 210, dtype: float64
```